# How to identify different of characters from two string

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need the different of characters between two words

```
example= (1) Sunday (2) Sundey
different character i need **e**

example= (1) Monday (2) Monbuy
different character i need **bu**
```

Comment: In Java or in Kotlin?

Comment: @mehul Added the solution, Kindly Check

Answer (score 1):

Have tested with the input you have given, working perfectly in those cases

```
private static String getDifferentChar(String data, String compareWithData) {

    if(data == null || compareWithData == null) return null;
    int dataLength = data.length();
    int compareWithDataLength = compareWithData.length();

    String differentChar = "";
    int pos =0;

    if(pos<dataLength && compareWithDataLength >=dataLength) {
       while(pos<dataLength) {
      if(data.charAt(pos) != compareWithData.charAt(pos)) {
        differentChar+= "" + compareWithData.charAt(pos);
        }
             pos++;
       }

        if(compareWithDataLength > dataLength) {
             differentChar+= "" + compareWithData.substring(dataLength);
        }

    } 
    return differentChar;

}
```

Comment: it return the whole string at place where the word wrong like word substance and i put subsence than return tance i need only change word "t"&"e"

Comment: Both words can be of different length?

Comment: Here substance is of 9 and subsence is of 8 length, and we are comparing the position to check char at particular position is same or not. Just give me clear requirement so that can fix and update it

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein distance suddently comes to mind: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-levenshtein-distance-computing-algorithm

It calculates the necessary amount of insertion, deletion and exchanges to convert one string to another, you may easily change it to fit your own criteria for string difference.